# How do I select N rows and THEN order them?

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I want to select 100 rows from a table, and THEN order those 100 rows. This SQL:

```
select * from (select top 100 * from myTable) top100 order by myColumn
```

is very slow and seems to be ordering the entire table and then taking the top 100.

Whereas this SQL:

```
select top 100 from myTable
```

is quite fast

EDIT:

The first query is definitely ordering the entire table and then selecting the top 100

I am using Sybase 15

Comment: Your query looks correct to me.

Comment: Any indexes on the table?  The optimizer will build the query plan for the whole retrieval, then stop after the number of rows is returned.  If there are not indexes, or poor indexes then it could take a while as it has to do a table scan.

Comment: Also, would probably be more helpful to compare performance of your first query to `select top 100 * from myTable ORDER BY myColumn`

Comment: Yes!! Why does an `order by` on the outer query change the results of the subquery in Sybase? In SqlServer, this works like I'd expect (the subquery is executed first and then you can order its results using an outer query).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to a slow query isn't usually to change the syntax, but to look at the table.  In your case, at the indexes.

The difference between

```
select top 100 from myTable
```

and

```
select top 100 from myTable order by myRow -- (really?  myRow?  Not myColumn?)
```

is that the first query is meaningless.  Tables have no order, so the "top" 100 really means just *any* 100.  Not sure you could sell that to Casey Kasem.

Better than nonstandard `top`, [produce a real ranking](http://www.schemamania.org/sql/#rank.rows) by joining the table to itself, and limit the output with `WHERE myRow <= 100`.

Make sure there's an index with `myRow` as the first column.  The seek complexity for an indexed column is *O(log n)*, which will answer to millions of rows in seconds on pretty ordinary hardware.

Comment: the first query is not meaningless, it returns 100 rows from the table and very quickly, I don't care how it selects these rows, and it does it fast enough with whatever indexes are present. Changing indexes is not an option. It would not take very long at all to order these rows, so it is clear that the second query is not selecting 100 rows in the same manner as the first query

Answer (score -1):

USE CTE:

EX:

```
;with mycte as   
(  
select top 100 from mytable  
)select * from mycte order by 1
```

Comment: Sybase ASE 12.5 (and also 15.0) doesn't support CTE :(

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you did not put ASC or DESC? For example in this code.

```
SELECT field1, field2,...fieldN table_name1, table_name2...ORDER BY field1, [field2...] [ASC [DESC]]
```

Comment: the SQL syntax is ok, pretty sure ASC is default